# Method call on a STA COM component is hung

Tags: com, com-interop, sta, mta

we have an .NET application which uses a COM dll, the ThreadingModel of this component is "Appartment"

The Application always hangs calling a COM interface method.

the DebugDiag analysis says the following

> The finalizer thread is probably tring to release an instance of an
>   STA COM component, and it is stuck waiting for the STA thread to
>   become available. To resolve this problem, call
>   Marshal.ReleaseComObject to clean up the references for all
>   apartment-threaded COM components that you have used in your code
>   deterministically (immediately), rather than waiting for the Finalizer
>   Thread to do it at a later time.

in the recommendation section, it has recommended to change the threading model to "Both" which i did and was working fine, but this cannot be done as we have an UI and is not recommended as per our design.

any idea what changes in our .NET application code can fix this issue.

**Stack trace**
there are two threads,  2 and 65 that are trying to call into the COM object which in on thread 45, i guess the STA thread
call stack of thread 2

[image]

call stack of thread 65

[image]

Comment: Not very likely that the DebugDiag message is accurate, you are still using the object.  You'll have to give us a look-see, at least the full stack trace of the hung call.

Comment: added the call stack information , thank you for looking into this

Comment: Well, the DebugDiag message was accurate, the finalizer thread is deadlocked.  The second thread is not happy either, probably for the same reason.  Whatever STA thread owns the object (not visible) is no longer doing its duty, running the dispatcher.  Never block an STA thread.  With some luck you'll see it when you look at the UI thread, it is doing something unwise like waiting for that worker thread that calls get_Data() to complete.